# REGEX: Maximum length and number of occurrences

Tags: .net, regex

I'm forced to write a regular expression that limits the input string to a maximum length of 250 characters, and a maximum of seven lines. These need to be in a single regular expression.

Separately I would write:

```
^.{0,250}$ // max length
^([^\r\n]*[\r\n][^\r\n]*){0,6}$ //maximum seven lines
```

combining them using
(?=..)(?=..) doesn't seem to work on https://www.debuggex.com/

Is there any way this can be done in a single regular expression?

EDIT: this is .NET

Comment: Regex languages vary wildly.  Please specify which dialect of regex (i.e., which programming language) you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
(?s)^(?!(?:[^\r\n]*\r?\n){7}).{0,250}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?s)       # Mode modifier: Dot matches newlines
^          # Match start of string
(?!        # Assert that it's impossible to match...
 (?:       # (Start of group):
  [^\r\n]* # Any number of characters except newlines
  \r?\n    # followed by one Windows or Mac/Unix newline
 ){7}      # repeated seven times
)          # End of lookahead assertion
.{0,250}   # Match up to 250 characters of any kind
$          # Match end of string
```